# How to generate the signing certificate fingerprint of phone app on HarmonyOS watch to be communicated with?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have a problem getting the signing certificate fingerprint for my Android app for the communication between phone and Huawei GT2 Pro that is a HarmonyOS watch.  I follow the instruction of Wear Engine SDK integration process at the Huawei developer website (https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/service-introduction-0000000000018585) to develop my app on both phone and watch. However, it is not very clear to me how to generate the signing certificate fingerprint. Can someone help to describe the process?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are at the debug stage. You need use the debug certificate, i.e., the .cer certificate that you obtain in AppGallery Connect (AGC) to generate the signing certificate fingerprint. Here is the procedure:

Step 1 – use Huawei DevEco Studio to generate a key store (in p12 format) and a certificate signing request file (.csr);

Step 2- login your Huawei account on AGC, and use the .csr file to apply and download the debug .cer certificate file from the Certificate management that is under the Users and permissions on AGC;

Step 3 – open the .cer file and copy information in the last paragraph to the new text .cer file, and then open the new .cer file and click Details, then Public key to obtain the pubKey;

Step 4 -  use a 3rd party online tool tomeko.net to encode the pubKey to base64 format, finally the base64Encode(pubKey) is the signing certificate fingerprint. You can find the detail of pubKey and base64 generation in https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/connectivity-Guides/signature-0000001053969657.